# Paging and listing in Beamer

Tags: beamer, page-numbering

[image]

First question:

I would like to know how to add the groups of circles on top of slides that allow me to go to a slide of a specific topic by clicking a circle. The circles are shown in the slide posted above. So, if I click on a circle under "Estimation," I will go to a slide about estimation.

Second question:

I would like to know how I can create a list with the numbering 1, 2, 3, and so on as shown at the bottom of the slide. In LaTeX, numbers in a list are always inside blue circle. How can I create the numbering that exactly looks like the one in the slide above?

Comment: Use `\usetheme{Singapore}`

Comment: How can I create the titles at the bottom of the slide such as "ECO 2408 H1F U. of Toronto" and "15.b 2SLS in Matrix Algebra"?

Comment: Please see the update of my answer below.

Comment: Thanks, a lot, Harish. Now I have completed my presentation slides for my course.

Comment: By the way, how did you learn all the programming skills for using LaTeX/Tex and Beamer?

Comment: By reading!. Please remember that you can accept answers that have solved your problem. For details, refer: [How do you accept an answer](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1852/how-do-you-accept-an-answer)

Answer (score 2):

Those circles are provided by `Singapore` theme. and to get only numbers in the enumerate, you have to provide a mini template like

```
\begin{enumerate}[1.]
```

To make this work for all `enumerate` environments put `\setbeamertemplate{enumerate items}[default]` in the preamble as commented by Gonzalo.

Full code

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{Singapore}
\useinnertheme{rounded}
%\setbeamercolor*{normal text}{fg=black,bg=violet!15}
\usecolortheme{rose}
\begin{document}
  \section{Some}
  \begin{frame}
    Some text
    \begin{enumerate}[1.]
      \item one
      \item two
    \end{enumerate}
  \end{frame}
  \subsection{Subsection}
  \begin{frame}
    Some text
  \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want footer also, you have to do extra work.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{Singapore}
\useinnertheme{rounded}
\setbeamercolor*{normal text}{fg=black,bg=violet!15}
\makeatletter
\defbeamertemplate*{footline}{mytheme}
{%
  \leavevmode%
  \hbox{\begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=0.35\paperwidth,ht=2.5ex,dp=1.125ex,leftskip=.3cm plus1fill,rightskip=.3cm,center]{author in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{author in head/foot}\insertshortauthor
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=0.35\paperwidth,ht=2.5ex,dp=1.125ex,leftskip=.3cm,rightskip=.3cm plus1fil,center]{title in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}\insertshorttitle
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=0.3\paperwidth,ht=2.5ex,dp=1.125ex,leftskip=.3cm,rightskip=.3cm plus1fil]{author in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}\insertshortdate\hfill
    \insertframenumber/\inserttotalframenumber
  \end{beamercolorbox}}%
  \vskip0pt%
}
\makeatother
\setbeamercolor*{structure}{bg=red!50,fg=olive}

\setbeamercolor*{palette primary}{use=structure,fg=white,bg=structure.fg!90}
% \setbeamercolor*{palette secondary}{use=structure,fg=white,bg=structure.fg!75}
%\setbeamercolor*{palette tertiary}{use=structure,fg=white,bg=structure.fg!50!black}
%\setbeamercolor*{palette quaternary}{fg=white,bg=structure}

\author{Ghost}
\title[my title]{This is some presentation}
\institute{Some institute}

\begin{document}
  \begin{frame}
    \titlepage
  \end{frame}
  \section{Some}
  \begin{frame}
    Some text
    \begin{enumerate}[1.]
      \item one
      \item two
    \end{enumerate}
  \end{frame}
  \subsection{Subsection}
  \begin{frame}
    Some text
  \end{frame}
  \subsection{Subsection}
  \begin{frame}
    test text
  \end{frame}

  \section{Test Section One One}
  \begin{frame}
    test text
  \end{frame}

  \subsection{Subsection}
  \begin{frame}
    test text
  \end{frame}

  \subsection{Subsection}
  \begin{frame}
    test text
  \end{frame}

  \section{Test Section One One}
  \begin{frame}
    test text
  \end{frame}

  \subsection{Subsection}
  \begin{frame}
    test text
  \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: To use `\begin{enumerate}[1.]...\end{enumerate}` implies doing this for every `enumerate` environment. It's better to say `\setbeamertemplate{enumerate items}[default]` in the preamble (or `\setbeamertemplate{enumerate item}[default]` just for the first nesting level).